# Do I have to bottle my wine immediately after stopping the fermentation?

Tags: wine, racking

I have a gallon of very sweet kiwi wine. I've racked it twice already but after couple months in at it's current stage it still hasn't cleared. I want to let it sit in the carboy until it does clear but at the same time I don't want it to continue getting stronger (the wine is very sweet so there is plenty of sugar still to be eaten and for some reason the yeast seems to be pushing well beyond its nominal tolerance of 14% ABV).

Is it ok for me to stop the fermentation now (with campden tablets and Potassium Sorbate) but leave the wine in carboy for a few more months until it clears? Or will it spoil? If that's OK, should I sterilise with Campden tablets once more before bottling to prevent spoilage?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is how most wine is made and aged before it's bottled. It's not uncommon for red wines to sit in a barrel or a stainless tank for 2-3 years. As long as you keep the sulfite levels in the right range, you can keep it like that for literally years. As for sulfites before bottling, again you want them to be at a level (as high as 200ppm) to prevent the wine from fermenting anymore.